# DateTime in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas, cube

I have a DateTime column in my Time dimension table. I want to display this as just MM/DD/YYYY and hide the time component (which is 00:00:00 anyways).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Raj, I wouldn't alter this particular field because it may cause problems with ordering and calculations when browsing or pulling data from the deployed cube. What I would do is add another field to your time dimension say...SHORT_DATE and simply make it a varchar(10).
I always keep at least one proper datetime in my [TIME] dimension for date dependant usage.

Comment: @Aajdamns: I agree with you about not change the data type. I do not want to change the data type - I just want to change the Display Format.

Comment: Then I would just make another column in your TIME dimension and go from there. What I did in mine was make an actual hierarchy of varchar dates and then I ordered them by the key which you can do in the properties on the lower right side of BIDS when you have your hierarchy selected.